a questions about darts
I am using tide model in darts and i didn't use pat covariants at all; but i got this error: ValueError: Missing covariates; could not find past covariates in index value range: 19 - 19. start is 3, end is 4，covariate_series.time_index is RangeIndex(start=42, stop=61, step=1, name='time');
I am trying to build a universal model for a dataset with multiple time series. a lot of univarient time series. and I am not very familar with darts yet.  here is the link for darts: https://unit8co.github.io/darts/examples/01-multi-time-series-and-covariates.html Any suggestions? thank you
And here is my code
#build a simple tide model
def build_fit_tide_model(
    input_chunk_length,
    output_chunk_length,
    temporal_width_past,
    temporal_width_future,
    num_encoder_layers,
    num_decoder_layers,
    temporal_decoder_hidden,
    dropout,
    batch_size,
    decoder_output_dim,
    optimizer_kwargs,
    hidden_size,
    n_epochs,
    # pl_trainer_kwargs ,
    random_state ,
    use_static_covariates ,
    model_name ,
    force_reset,
    save_checkpoints,
    callbacks=None
):
#reproducibility
torch.manual_seed(42)
# some fixed parameters that will be the same for all models
use_static_covariates = True,
optimizer_kwargs = {"lr": 1e-3},
use_reversible_instance_norm = False,
pl_trainer_kwargs = {"accelerator": "cpu"}
random_state = 42

# throughout training we'll monitor the validation loss for early stopping
early_stopper = EarlyStopping("val_loss", min_delta=0.001, patience=3, verbose=True)
if callbacks is None:
    callbacks = [early_stopper]
else:
    callbacks = [early_stopper] + callbacks
pl_trainer_kwargs['callbacks'] = callbacks
#
# # optionally also add the day of the week (cyclically encoded) as a past covariate
# encoders = {"cyclic": {"past": ["dayofweek"]}} if include_dayofweek else None

# build the TiDEModel model
model = TiDEModel(
    input_chunk_length=input_chunk_length,
    output_chunk_length= output_chunk_length,
    temporal_width_past = temporal_width_past,
    temporal_width_future = temporal_width_future,
    num_encoder_layers = num_encoder_layers,
    num_decoder_layers=num_decoder_layers,
    temporal_decoder_hidden = temporal_decoder_hidden,
    dropout=dropout,
    batch_size=batch_size,
    # n_epochs=100,
    n_epochs=2,
    decoder_output_dim = 1,
    optimizer_kwargs= {"lr": 1e-3},
    pl_trainer_kwargs=pl_trainer_kwargs,
    random_state = 42,
    use_static_covariates = True,
    model_name = "tide_model",
    force_reset = True,
    save_checkpoints = True,
    hidden_size=15,
)

# when validating during training, we can use a slightly longer validation
# set which also contains the first input_chunk_length time steps
# model_val_set = scaler.transform(
#     [s[-((2 * val_len) + in_len) : -val_len] for s in all_series_fp32]
# )
# model_val_set = val[val_len:]
model_val_set = val

# train the model
model.fit(
    series=train,
    future_covariates = train_dynamic_covariates_transformed,
    val_series=model_val_set,
    val_future_covariates = val_dynamic_covariates_transformed, 
    verbose=False
)

# reload best model over course of training
model = TiDEModel.load_from_checkpoint("tide_model")
return model
model_v1 = build_fit_tide_model(
    input_chunk_length = 2,
    output_chunk_length = 1,
    temporal_width_past = 1,
    temporal_width_future = 3,
    num_encoder_layers=2,
    num_decoder_layers=4,
    temporal_decoder_hidden=2,
    dropout = 0.4,
    batch_size=28,
    n_epochs = 2,
    decoder_output_dim = 1,
    optimizer_kwargs = {"lr": 1e-3},
    random_state=42,
    use_static_covariates=True,
    model_name="tide_model",
    force_reset=True,
    save_checkpoints=True,
    hidden_size=15)

`
